# Flutter bloc state is not emitting or updating. Method mapEventToState is never called

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

The following code was working before null safety with flutter_bloc 4.0.1 but after null safety migration the state is not updating / emitting / broadcasting as expected with flutter_bloc 7.3.3.

The below `_reactToState` and `mapEventToState` methods are never called. How can I fix it?

**Splash Screen**

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Strapper strapper;
  final Service? service;

  SplashScreen(this.strapper, this.service);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  SplashBloc? _splashBloc;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_splashBloc == null) {
      _splashBloc = SplashBloc(widget.strapper, widget.service);

      _splashBloc!.stream.listen(_reactToState);
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _splashBloc?.close();
    _splashBloc = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<SplashBloc>(
      create: (context) => _splashBloc!,
      child: BlocBuilder<SplashBloc, SplashBlocState>(
        builder: (context, state) => Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              LogoPanel(
                _showWidgetForState(state),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _reactToState(SplashBlocState state) {
    if (state is InitializingSplashBlocState) {
      if (widget.logOut) {
        _splashBloc!.add(LogoutSplashBlocEvent());
      } else {
        _splashBloc!.add(CInitializationSplashBlocEvent());
      }
    } else if (state is AuthSuccessSplashBlocState) {
      App.navigateToSomewhere(context, state.isNewUser);
    }
  }

  Widget _showWidgetForState(SplashBlocState state) {
    if (state is InitializingSplashBlocState) {
      return _getProgressIndicator();
    } else if (state is ChooseSomethingSplashBlockState ) {
      return _showSignInWidget();
    }
  }
}
```

**Splash Bloc**

```
class SplashBloc extends Bloc<SplashBlocEvent, SplashBlocState> {
  final Strapper? strapper;
  final Service? service;

  SplashBloc(this.strapper, this.service) : super(InitializingSplashBlocState());

  @override
  Stream<SplashBlocState> mapEventToState(event) async* {
    if (event is CInitializationSplashBlocEvent) {
      await strapper!.run();
    }
    bool chooseSomething = !service!.hasSomeSelection;

    if (chooseSomething) {
      yield ChooseSomethingSplashBlockState();
    } else if (event is RAuthSplashBlocEvent) {
      yield AuthSplashBlocState();
      var authState = await _run();
      yield authState;
    } 
  }

  Future<SplashBlocState> _run() async {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

**Splash Bloc Event**

```
abstract class SplashBlocEvent extends Equatable {
  const SplashBlocEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CInitializationSplashBlocEvent extends SplashBlocEvent {}

class RAuthSplashBlocEvent extends SplashBlocEvent {}
```

**Splash Bloc State**

```
abstract class SplashBlocState extends Equatable {
  const SplashBlocState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InitializingSplashBlocState extends SplashBlocState {}

class AuthSplashBlocState extends SplashBlocState {}

class ChooseSomethingSplashBlockState extends SplashBlocState {}    

class AuthSuccessSplashBlocState extends SplashBlocState {
  final CurrentUser? user;
  final bool isNewUser;

  AuthSuccessSplashBlocState(this.user, this.isNewUser);
}
```

Comment: see my code below.  The splash screen should follow solid principle and separate concerns away from the interface by using bloc

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%E2%9D%97bloc-does-not-emit-last-state-on-subscription):

> In v6.0.0, the above snippet does not output the initial state and only outputs subsequent state changes. The previous behavior can be achieved with the following:
>
> ```
> final bloc = MyBloc();
> print(bloc.state);
> bloc.listen(print);
> ```

So I changed my code in the Splash screen as following:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_splashBloc == null) {
      _splashBloc = SplashBloc(widget.strapper, widget.service);
      _reactToState(_splashBloc!.state); // Added this line 
      _splashBloc!.stream.listen(_reactToState);
    }
  }
```

And that's it. It worked!
`_reactToState` and `mapEventToState` are definitely being called.

Answer (score 0):

when you use Streamcontrollers it greatly simplifies state.  I build a bloc code to manage state.   The materialapp child is the splashWidget whose job is to render the hour, minute, second from bloc code emitting Time state.  If the user clicks the splash screen or 5 seconds elapses the splash screen will be replaced with the HomePageWidget.  bloc code controls the starting and stopping of the timer using an timerState event.

```
'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bloc_splash.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class SplashWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

_redirectToHome(BuildContext context)
{
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(_)=>MyHomePage(title:"helloWorld")));

}
String _displayClock(Time ? data)
{
  String retVal="";
  if (data!=null)
  {
    retVal="Time: ${data.hour} : ${data.minute} : ${data.second}";
  }
  return retVal;

}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SplashBloc _bloc=SplashBloc();
    _bloc.timerOnChange(StartTimer());
   
    return Scaffold(

      body:InkWell(
              onTap: (){_bloc.timerOnChange(StopTimer());
              _redirectToHome(context);
              },
              child:Container(
                  child: 
          StreamBuilder<TimeState>(
            stream:_bloc.timeStream,
            builder:(context,snapshot)
            {
              if(snapshot.hasData && (snapshot.data is RedirectState))
              {
                return MyHomePage(title:"helloWorld");
              }
              return Center(child:Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                Text("Splash Screen", style:TextStyle(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(_displayClock(snapshot.data?.time)),
              ]));
            }
          )
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

bloc code

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';

abstract class TimerEvent extends Equatable{
  const TimerEvent();
  @override 
  List<Object>get props=>[];
}
class StartTimer extends TimerEvent{
  const StartTimer();
}
class StopTimer extends TimerEvent{
   const StopTimer();
}

class Time{
  final int hour;
  final int minute;
  final int second;
  Time(this.hour,this.minute,this.second);
}
class TimeState extends Equatable{
  final Time time;
  TimeState(this.time);
  @override
  List<Object> get props=>[time];
}
class RedirectState implements TimeState{
  final Time time;
  RedirectState(this.time);
  @override
  List<Object> get props=>[time];

  @override
  // TODO: implement stringify
  bool? get stringify => throw UnimplementedError();

}

class TimerState extends Equatable{
 final bool started;
 const TimerState(this.started);
 @override 
 List<Object> get props => [started];
}

class SplashBloc
{
   SplashBloc();
   Timer ?_timer;
   var countDown=5;
   Stream<TimeState> get timeStream=> _timeController.stream;
   final _timeController =BehaviorSubject<TimeState>();
   void dispose()
   {
      _timeController.close();
   }
   void _pushTimeOnTheStream(Timer timer)
   {
     DateTime now=DateTime.now();     
      _timeController.sink.add(TimeState(Time(now.hour,now.minute,now.second)));
      this.countDown-=1;
      if (this.countDown==0)
      {
        timerOnChange(StopTimer());
      _timeController.sink.add(RedirectState(Time(0,0,0)));
      }
   }
   void timerOnChange(TimerEvent event) { 
    if (event is StartTimer)
    {
      _timer=Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),_pushTimeOnTheStream);
    }
    else if(event is StopTimer){
       //_timerController.sink.add(TimerState(false)); 
       _timer?.cancel();
    }
 } 
}
```

app

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SplashWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```